# Hide keyboard on android application

Tags: android, keyboard

when i touch textedit, the keyboard android opens.

I want to stop that.

My code:

activity_main.xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_box"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="#ffffff">

</EditText>
```

Main.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        caixa = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_box);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(caixa.getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
```

Comment: If you don't want the EditText to be edited, why you don't just use a TextView?

Comment: I want to use EditText for several reasons. There is no way to hide the android keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the keyboard in the manifest:

```
<activity
...
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >

</activity>
```

Comment: not work...the keyboard continues open

My activity:


[code]<activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"><[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(caixa.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: I put this code in main.java inside the onCreate method?